# Function to regress chosen variable against all others

Tags: r, function, regression

In my dataset I have 6 variables(x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6), i wish to create a function that allows me to input one variable and it will do the formula with the rest of the variables in the data set.

For instance,

```
      fitRegression <- function(data, dependentVariable) {
      fit = lm(formula = x1 ~., data = data1) 
      return(fit) 
      }

      fitRegression(x2)
```

However, this function only returns me with results of x1. My desire result will be inputting whatever variables and will automatically do the formula with the rest of the variables.

For Example:

```
      fitRegression(x2)
```

should subtract x2 from the variable list therefore we only compare x2 with x1,x3,x4,x5,x6.

and if:

```
     fitRegression(x3)
```

should subtract x3 from the comparable list, therefore we compare x3 with x1,x2,x4,x5,x6.

Is there any ways to express this into my function, or even a better function.

Comment: Didn't you ask this question a couple of hours ago?

Comment: one method is to enter the dependent variable as a string, then use `lm(formula = reformulate(dependentVariable, "x1"), data = data1)`.

Comment: @Sotos the question was vague before and I could'nt find much solution online.

Comment: Ok. Just note that it is preferable to edit the original question and add information to make it clearer. Also by including some reproducible example for us to play with you will get a lot more help. - Hence my suggestion to your previous question was untested.

Comment: Should x1 be in the list of what you want to compare x2 and x3 to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
# sample data
sampleData <- data.frame(matrix(rnorm(500),100,5))
colnames(sampleData) <- c("A","B","C","D","E")

# function
fitRegression <- function(mydata, dependentVariable) {

  # select your independent and dependent variables
  dependentVariableIndex<-which(colnames(mydata)==dependentVariable)
  independentVariableIndices<-which(colnames(mydata)!=dependentVariable)

  fit = lm(formula = as.formula(paste(colnames(mydata)[dependentVariableIndex], "~", paste(colnames(mydata)[independentVariableIndices], collapse = "+"), sep = "" )), data = mydata) 
  return(fit) 
}

# ground truth
lm(formula = A~B+C+D+E, data = sampleData)

# reconcile results
fitRegression(sampleData, "A")
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to select the Y variable in your argument. The main difficulty is to pass this argument without any quotes in your function (it is apparently the expected result in your code). Therefore you can use this method, using the combination `deparse(substitute(...))`:

```
fitRegression <- function(data, dependentVariable) {
  formula <- as.formula(paste0(deparse(substitute(dependentVariable)), "~."))
  return(lm(formula, data) ) 
}

fitRegression(mtcars, disp)
```

That will return the model.

Answer (score 1):

The below function uses "purrr" and "caret" it produces a list of models.

```
df <-mtcars
library(purrr);library(caret)
#create training set
vect <- createDataPartition(1:nrow(df), p=0.8, list = FALSE)
#build model list
ModList <- 1:length(df) %>% 
  map(function(col) train(y= df[vect,col], x= df[vect,-col], method="lm"))
```

Comment: It produces a list of all possible models but each one bootstraped 25 times... not sure it's exactly what the OP wants but nice job! just a remark: i think you meant `purrr` and not `purr`